# Traefik + Let's Encrypt on AWS Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, traefik, lets-encrypt, amazon-lightsail

I'm currently using [Traefik](https://traefik.io/traefik/) and  [Lego](https://go-acme.github.io/lego) in order to have HTTPS connection for my docker containers (as mentioned [here](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/user-guides/docker-compose/acme-dns/))
In the following [documentation](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/https/acme/), it's mentioned that I need to use the following [provider](https://go-acme.github.io/lego/dns/lightsail/) to do DNS Challenge.

But I get this error:

```
AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::<USER_ID>:assumed-role/AmazonLightsailInstanceRole/<AN_ID> is not authorized to perform: lightsail:CreateDomainEntry on resource: arn:aws:lightsail:us-east-1:<INSTANCE_ID>:*
```

and another for DeleteDomainEntry, even though I have `lightsail:*` on `Resource: *` permission on the IAM user used for configuration.

If I understand correctly Lightsail is managed separately for the other AWS services and thus we need to use STS for connecting to it (tell me if I'm wrong). So my question is this, how can I set the permissions for the temporary token to be able to do CreateDomainEntry and DeleteDomainEntry?

### Further information

- My instance's region is `eu-west-3` (I tried changing the region in Lego config, doesn't work)
- The <USER_ID> seen in the error does not correspond to the id found in the ARN of the domain. It correspond to the first number in the `supportCode` when doing `aws lightsail get-domains --region us-east-1` in the CLI.
- Lego and Traefik do not call the AssumeRole directly and do not create the temporary token (checked source code)
- I'm using `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_FILE` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_FILE` in Traefik environment configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were too many confusing things. [Martin Löper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10473469/martin-l%c3%b6per)'s answer  and [answer on the github issue I opened](https://github.com/go-acme/lego/issues/1436) helped me to clear things out.

Here is what was confusing:

- Lego [lightsail provider documentation](https://go-acme.github.io/lego/dns/lightsail/) is listing the environment variable and then say `The environment variable names can be suffixed by _FILE to reference a file instead of a value`. Turns out, Lego's code never call their [getOrFile](https://github.com/go-acme/lego/blob/284d1a3e384ca8f16585825ccef5f27241604824/platform/config/env/env.go#L146) method on the credentials. Furthermore, AWS sdk does not check variables with the `_FILE` suffix for `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.
- The error message from AWS is little bit misleading. I thought all that time that it was a permission problem but in fact it was a authentication problem (little bit different in my opinion).

And here is how to solve it (little bit different from what proposed):

I use the `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` (mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html)) environment variable so that I can use docker secrets by specifying `/run/secrets/aws_shared_credentials` file. This is more secure (more info [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/)). AWS sdk will automatically detect this env variable and initialize this [new session](https://github.com/go-acme/lego/blob/284d1a3e384ca8f16585825ccef5f27241604824/providers/dns/lightsail/lightsail.go#L105) correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells that Lego made the request using the IAM role assigned to your lightsail instance. I guess your instance lacks permissions to modify DNS settings for lightsail.

You should create a new user in AWS IAM and enable programmatic access in order to obtain *AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID* and *AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY*.

Then, pass those values as environment variables to your containers running Lego. Lego will use those env vars to authenticate with Lightsail APIs in us-east-1. [1]

> My instance's region is eu-west-3 (I tried changing the region in Lego config, doesn't work)

Your Lego instance must call AWS APIs in us-east-1, see [2][3].

> Lego and Traefik do not call the AssumeRole directly and do not create the temporary token

I guess Traefik/Lego assume the lightsail instance role automatically using EC2 instance metadata service, see [4]:

> For applications, AWS CLI, and Tools for Windows PowerShell commands that run on the instance, you do not have to explicitly get the temporary security credentials—the AWS SDKs, AWS CLI, and Tools for Windows PowerShell automatically get the credentials from the EC2 instance metadata service and use them. To make a call outside of the instance using temporary security credentials (for example, to test IAM policies), you must provide the access key, secret key, and the session token.

> I'm using AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_FILE and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_FILE in Traefik environment configuration.

I could not find those env vars in the Lego source code [1]. Make sure that Lego is actually using your configured AWS credentials. The error message posted above suggests it's not using them and falls back to the instance profile instead.

[1] https://github.com/go-acme/lego/blob/master/providers/dns/lightsail/lightsail.go#L81
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lightsail/create-domain-entry.html#examples
[3] https://github.com/go-acme/lego/blob/master/providers/dns/lightsail/lightsail.go#L69
[4] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#instance-metadata-security-credentials